# Get authors post in wordpress with co-author plus installed

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to list all posts, a user is assigned as author.
We are using the plugin, co-authors plus, which allows to assign multiple authors to a single post.
The function `<?php $user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userid ); ?>` returns the correct number of posts, the user is assigned to.
But when trying to list all the posts, with The loop only the post which initially were created by that user are shown.

```
query_posts( $args );

if (count_user_posts($user->ID) == 0) {
    echo "No posts";
}

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Is there an other possibility to get all posts from an user or can we modify our existing code?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $user_login
        )
    ),
);
$author_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $author_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post();

    // Do your presentation

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: This has the same result as descriped above. Only lists the post, which the author initially created.

Comment: Ok did some research and looks like this plugin is using taxonomy to save the posts for different authors, in order to show them check out my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param $user_id
 * @param int $paged (if $paged = null return all posts)
 * @return array|bool
 */
function get_coauthor_posts_by_author_id($id, $paged = 1)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $slug = 'cap-' . strtolower(get_userdata($id)->user_nicename);


    $max_post = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $post_lower_limit = 0;


    if ($paged > 1) {
        $post_upper_limit = $max_post * $paged;
        $post_lower_limit = $post_upper_limit - $max_post;

    }


    $term_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE slug = %s ", $slug))[0]->term_id;


    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  $wpdb->posts.id FROM $wpdb->posts  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr1 ON ($wpdb->posts.id = tr1.object_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ( tr1.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (($wpdb->posts.post_author = %d OR ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'author' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = %d))) AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.id  ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
    $sql_limit = " LIMIT %d, %d";
    if ($paged !== null) {
        $sql = $sql . $sql_limit;
    }



        $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql, $id, $term_id, $post_lower_limit, $max_post), ARRAY_A);
        return array_column($result, 'id');


}
```

Comment: Explain please!

Comment: Coauthor plus save author name as taxonomy during saving. But if you don't run re-save then the author name save as post author in post table. So I run a query using author id where it gets post ids of this author and gets the author term to find post ids for this author from author taxonomy. Using this function we can get all the posts for an author. You may debug the SQL for better understanding.